# wpf - One ViewModel that interacts with multiple instances of a Model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a WorkspaceViewModel that handles addition and deletion of tab items dynamically through an ObservableCollection. Each time a tab is connected to a PayslipModel, all bindings work fine but one problem I am having is that;

I have a save button in the UserControl who's DataContext is set to WorkspaceViewModel and I would like to save whatever info is being displayed in the selected tab. Now, each time a tab is added, a new instance of PayslipModel is created, which is exactly what I want because I don't want bindings to be shared for all tabs. However, I am unable to save what is being displayed since PayslipModel has multiple instances, therefore nothing is returned (temporarily using MessageBox to test if info is being retrieved) when I hit save.

I created a diagram to better explain my situation:
[image]

Is it possible to access the current instance when a tab is selected or cycle through all instances and do something like batch saving?

Comment: TabControl.Selected .DataContext as PaySlipModel ?

Comment: ItemsControls have an ItemsSource and SelectedItem.  In a TabControl SelectedItem is the currently displayed tab.  Is that not enough to tell you which PayslipModel is being edited?

Comment: @Will, I was trying to implement saving through the ViewModel since I bind the button using a command. Does that mean for this particular case, it cannot be done through the ViewModel?

Comment: @Patrick, same question ^

Comment: @bruh1234 If I understand you, the button code behind doesn't have access to TabControl, therefore bind a property in the ViewModel to TabControl SelectedItem...., then in button codebehind look at said property.

Comment: @Patrick, that doesn't seem to be working either so I thought of moving the save button inside the view that has the tab content, so it can directly access the properties. It does disrupt the flow of the layout but it's something I can work with for now.

Comment: You can always pass in the object you wish to save via the CommandParameter.  You'll see patterns like `<Button Content="{Binding Name, StringFormat=Save {0}}" Command="{Binding Save, ElementName=MainWindow" CommandParameter="{Binding}" />` where MainWindow is where the VM with the Save command lives, and the button is bound to the child VM.

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example which shows one of the possiblities:

**View**

```
    <TabControl DataContext="{Binding}" ItemsSource="{Binding Models}"  >
        <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" > 
                </TextBlock>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Top" Content="Click Me" Command="{Binding DataContext.PCommand, 
                                                            RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabControl}}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Desc}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Desc}" >
                    </TextBlock>
                </DockPanel> 
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

**Model View**

```
public class ModelView
{
    public ModelView()
    {
        _models = new ObservableCollection<Model>(); 
        _pCommand = new Command(DoParameterisedCommand);
    }
    ObservableCollection<Model> _models;
    public ObservableCollection<Model> Models { get { return _models; } }

    private void DoParameterisedCommand(object parameter)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Parameterised Command; Parameter is '" +
                     parameter.ToString() + "'.");
    }
    Command _pCommand;
    public Command PCommand
    {
        get { return _pCommand; }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _desc;
    public string Desc { get { return _desc; } set { _desc = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Desc"); } }

    string _name;
    public string Name { get { return _name; } set { _name = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Name"); } }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

**Command**

```
public class Command : ICommand
{ 
    public Command(Action<object> parameterizedAction, bool canExecute = true)
    {
        _parameterizedAction = parameterizedAction;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }


    Action<object> _parameterizedAction = null;
    bool _canExecute = false;
    public bool CanExecute
    {
        get { return _canExecute; }
        set
        {
            if (_canExecute != value)
            {
                _canExecute = value;
                CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return _canExecute;
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        this.DoExecute(parameter);
    }
    public virtual void DoExecute(object param)
    { if (_parameterizedAction != null)
            _parameterizedAction(param);
        else
            throw new Exception();
    }


}
```

Use this to initialize:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ModelView mv = new ModelView();
        mv.Models.Add(new Model() { Name = "a", Desc = "aaa" });
        mv.Models.Add(new Model() { Name = "b" , Desc = "bbb"});
        mv.Models.Add(new Model() { Name = "c", Desc = "cccc" });
        this.DataContext = mv; 

    }
```